# What the difference between a flattening validation curve and one that increases again?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training, cross-validation, data-science-model

I know that we monitor the validation loss to investigate overfitting. I am familiar with the validation curve that first decreases and then increases again. The increasing part means the model starts to overfit. However, I am not sure to understand and explain a validation loss that first decreases and then flattens. What is the difference between the 2? what is the relationship between capacity and the size of the available dataset?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The validation set trick is, among others, a regularization technique, which, roughly speaking, prevents the model from overfitting the data. At its core is just a statistical approximation to theoretically hard problems.

On one hand, if the validation loss decreases and then increases, the model starts to overfit and an early-stop condition is advisable to apply (e.g., if the validation loss does not decrease for 5 consecutive epochs).

On the other hand, if the validation decreases and then flattens, the model is *statistically* robust as the validation loss stables.

In case of doubt, you could cross-validate the problem.

I did not fully understand your last question. What is your definition for the capacity and size of the dataset? What type of relationship do you have in mind? I will continue my answer if you could further elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Per the learning book, "a model’s capacity is its ability to fit a wide variety of functions." For example, a second-order linear equation will have a greater capacity than a first-order one.  Therefore, the second-order is likelier to overfit than the first-order one. I wanted to see if I can explain these validation curves by using the capacity theory.